# Circuit with adjustable source and a diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, source

I'm struggling a bit with diode circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6LCrl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The source is **adjustable.**

1. Which value the source has to be to the Diode start conducting?
2. What's the value of entrance's current and the diode's current when the source is 10V?

Any explanation on why/how the diode will start conducting at certain value will help!

Comment: Assuming you can assume the diode to be ideal, there are only two cases: the diode conducts or it doesn't. Assume it doesn't. what is the voltage across the diode ? You need to use the voltage divider formula for this. Write down the formula. The diode will start to conduct when Vdiode > 0 (or take a more realistic value if you prefer). What does V1 need to be to satisfy this condition ?

Comment: Now that you have the formulas it is easy to do the calculation for V1 = 10 V. Is Vdiode > 0 then ? I bet it is so it will be in forward. Replace it with a short or with a DC voltage source (if you want it to drop 0.6 V for example) and recalculate.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Hi, so: it's a Si diode (~0.7v) using the voltage divider formula: The voltage across has to be bigger than 0.7 so I go for this: 0.7 = (Vin*2k)/(1k+2k), isolating Vin, I get Vin = 1.05. Is this right?

Comment: Left side: 1.05 * 2/3 = 0.7 V; right side: 1.05 * 1/3 = 0.35 V Then across the diode that's 0.7 - 0.35 V = 0.35 V so no, that is incorrect. Now **think hard** because I already "see" the answer from this calculation. *Note that the 2/3 and 1/3 I use is the transfer of the voltage dividers R1/(R1+R2) and R3/(R3+R4)*

Comment: I didn't consider the right side, my bad, so our Vin'd be 2.1V(we want ~0.7).

Comment: Exactly, the diode voltage scales linearly with V1 as long as the diode is not conducting so your answer was a factor 2 too low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if the left side is 2/3 of V+ and the right side is 1/3 of V+
- then the diode drop is now
  = Vf = (2/3 - 1/3) * V+
- So what V+ starts conduction for Vf=0.6V?

@arthurg et al... Next question.

- When diode conducts what happens to over all current from source.
- How much does the network resistance change? from what to what?

Answer:

- Using parallel (//) equivalents below and above threshold
- Diode OFF , R_tot= (1+2) // (2+1) =  3//3 = 1.5  [kΩ]
- then assume Diode Resistance much less or << 1 kΩ ( like a short circuit )
- Diode ON  , R_tot= (1//2) + (2//1)= 2/3 + 2/3 = 4/3 [kΩ]

**So impedance change is 1.5 to 1.33 [kΩ] for V+ > 1.8V**

Comment: V+ = 1.8V, simple and straight help, that was a great anwser!

Comment: gratuities are done by sending coffee...

Answer (score 0):

If you searched for a typical voltage versus current graph for any number of silicon diodes you would find something like this: -

[image]

As you can see, the diode is forward conducting at certainly 0.7 volts but, doesn't appear to be conducting if the forward voltage reduces to maybe 0.4 volts.

That's what this simplistic graph tells you but it isn't true. Take a look at a logarithmic graph of forward voltage and forward current: -

[image]

It's a striaght line and you can see that every tenfold reduction in current is brought about by a forward volt drop reduction of about 100 mV. As current eventually falls towards zero that relationship starts to become a linear relationship with 0 V and 0 nA being truly representative at the origin of the graph.

This means that a diode is always conducting unless the applied voltage is exactly zero.

Given that the circuit in the question has a more positive bias voltage at the anode compared to the cathode, whenever there is a positive voltage produced by the source, there will be forward conduction of *some* current.

If you were to ask a question that said what voltage would be the source when say 1 mA flowed or maybe when the forward voltage became 0.7 volts that would be different.