# Why current appears at reverse bias?

Tags: current, diodes, reverse-bias

I am simulating time-domain graphs of a Schottky diode model.

[image]

I am expecting ~zero current at the negative half cycle. But I am seeing negative current. It's only about 3mA, but based on I-V curve, it is about 0. Does anyone have an idea what might go wrong?

[image]
[image]

diode model:(from datasheet)
Is=30e15     Rs=8     N=1.05      Tg=1e-9   Cjo=0.1e-12     Vj=1     M=0.5   Fc=0.95     BV=5    IBV=1e-5     Eg=0.69

Comment: Reverse recovery time?

Comment: Since  I is 90 degrees out of phase with V I'll go with "What is capacitive coupling Alex?"

Comment: wait ... PICOseconds? That's 11GHz. Does your diode model include capacitance?

Comment: @immibis Just edited the post. It should be a schottky diode.  We should have nearly 0 reverse recovery time... right?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Just added the diode model... CJO is 0.1pF Yes, I am setting freq to 11GHz.. pretty high.. I am curious about how it looks a high frequency.

Comment: @Missfresstyle try replacing it with a 0.1pF cap and see what you get.....

Comment: If you actually have `Is=30e15` instead of `Is=30e-15` that's gonna mess you up too.

Comment: So Xc=144 ohms between a 50 ohm source and a 50 ohm termination. Look no further (see Trevor's answer). (Second order effect : note that current is asymmetric, and slightly higher on the -ve half cycle : I think you're in the region where reverse recovery provides better conduction than forward conduction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that frequency you have this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fARCYp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have some reverse leakage current for all diodes, for instance a 1N4001 is specced at \$5\mu A\$ at \$25\circ\$C. But that's not what's happening here.

The more likely culprit is the diode's turn off time. Your diode appears to be a silicon diode from the 0.7V knee, and silicon diodes have a non-negligible switching time, from a some \$ns\$ to several \$\mu s\$ or more ([more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBqLOrlA7QI)). That's exactly what your circuit looks like, as it seems the diode isn't turning off at all when you push it negative, and at 14 or so GHz (where you're at), this becomes VERY significant. For simulation, you'll want to alter your diode model, and if you actually intend to build this, you'll need to pay very careful attention to the type of diode you select.

Answer (score 0):

The phase shift is obviously diode junction capacitance just as any RC filter.

The diode negative constant current effect is shown here with a mainly negative biased sawtooth with autoscale.

171.44 nA leakage. but always reported as worst case leakage at max PIV

[image]